# Problema de ubicación de archivo clase en producción al imprimir con C#

Tags: c#, servidor, reportviewer, impresión, rutas

Resulta que cuando quiero imprimir en desde el sitio web de producción, me sale un error de una ubicación errónea del archivo clase. En el error, me muestra la ruta del proyecto que tengo ubicado:

**C:\Users\Usuario PC\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\Ejemplo\Ejemplo\Clases\PrintReport.cs**

Me parece ilógico que me muestre este error en la web de producción. Cuando lo pruebo de forma local, no tengo ningún problema.

Adjunto la foto del error:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Lo que estoy haciendo, es imprimir un documento de forma directa a la impresora por defecto usando reportviewer.

El archivo clase PrintReport.cs que uso es el siguiente:

```
public static class PrintReport
{
    private static int m_currentPageIndex;
    private static IList<Stream> m_streams;
    public static Stream CreateStream(string name,
      string fileNameExtension, Encoding encoding,
      string mimeType, bool willSeek)
    {
        Stream stream = new MemoryStream();
        m_streams.Add(stream);
        return stream;
    }

    public static void Export(LocalReport report, bool print = true)
    {
        string deviceInfo =
          @"<DeviceInfo>
            <OutputFormat>EMF</OutputFormat>
            <PageWidth>0</PageWidth>
            <PageHeight>0</PageHeight>
            <MarginTop>0</MarginTop>
            <MarginLeft>0</MarginLeft>
            <MarginRight>0</MarginRight>
            <MarginBottom>0</MarginBottom>
        </DeviceInfo>";
        Warning[] warnings;
        m_streams = new List<Stream>();
        report.Render("Image", deviceInfo, CreateStream,
           out warnings);
        foreach (Stream stream in m_streams)
            stream.Position = 0;

        if (print)
        {
            Print();
        }
    }


    // Handler for PrintPageEvents
    public static void PrintPage(object sender, PrintPageEventArgs ev)
    {
        Metafile pageImage = new
           Metafile(m_streams[m_currentPageIndex]);

        // Adjust rectangular area with printer margins.
        Rectangle adjustedRect = new Rectangle(
            ev.PageBounds.Left - (int)ev.PageSettings.HardMarginX,
            ev.PageBounds.Top - (int)ev.PageSettings.HardMarginY,
            ev.PageBounds.Width,
            ev.PageBounds.Height);

        // Draw a white background for the report
        ev.Graphics.FillRectangle(Brushes.White, adjustedRect);

        // Draw the report content
        ev.Graphics.DrawImage(pageImage, adjustedRect);

        // Prepare for the next page. Make sure we haven't hit the end.
        m_currentPageIndex++;
        ev.HasMorePages = (m_currentPageIndex < m_streams.Count);
    }

    public static void Print()
    {
        if (m_streams == null || m_streams.Count == 0)
            throw new Exception("Error: no stream to print.");
        PrintDocument printDoc = new PrintDocument();
        if (!printDoc.PrinterSettings.IsValid)
        {
            throw new Exception("Error: cannot find the default printer.");
        }
        else
        {
            printDoc.PrintPage += new PrintPageEventHandler(PrintPage);
            m_currentPageIndex = 0;
            printDoc.Print();
        }
    }

    public static void PrintToPrinter(this LocalReport report)
    {
        Export(report);
    }

    public static void DisposePrint()
    {
        if (m_streams != null)
        {
            foreach (Stream stream in m_streams)
                stream.Close();
            m_streams = null;
        }
    }
}
```

la Forma que lo llamo es así:

```
ReportViewer1.LocalReport.PrintToPrinter();
```

Me gustaría saber cual sería la causa del error, y como solucionarlo, ¿quizás, debo cambiar alguna propiedad de compilación y de copia de directorio del archivo PrintReport.cs?¿o sería otra cosa?¿Alguna idea?

Comment: Ya verificaste que el servidor de producción tenga una impresora predeterminada configurada?

Comment: No @Mauricio Atanache, pero en que afectaría, ya que yo imprimiría desde otro computador

Comment: @Danilo claro que afecta, debido a que tu aplicación web (que está en un servidor) está tratando de obtener una impresora predeterminada configurada. A ver si te hago entender, la relación sería [Cliente (Explorador Web)] - [Aplicación Web (Servidor Web)] - [Dispositivo Impresión]. De ninguna manera sería [Cliente (Explorador Web)] - [Dispositivo Impresión], ya que este último es como imprimiendo desde tu explorador un archivo. Ahora, De forma local funciona debido a que tu PC se comporta como Servidor Web y de seguro tiene configurado una impresora.

Comment: Y en este caso, en el servidor no debería tener impresora predeterminada? como debería estar configurada?

Comment: @Danilo **sencillamente el código que pones aplica para una aplicación de escritorio** y no para una aplicación web, debido a que estás mal orientado. Repito que el código que indicas sirve para que el Servidor Web (donde está publicado tu aplicación web) se encargue de imprimir un documento a una impresora que tenga configurado. Seguro que consideraste [Tutorial: Imprimir un informe local sin vista previa](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/ms252091.aspx)

Comment: Entiendo lo que quieres decir @Davlio, pero en mi caso, en vez de utilizar la librería using Microsoft.Reporting.WinForms, utilizo using Microsoft.Reporting.WebForm ya que también está para web. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms251837.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396

Pero como dije antes en la pregunta, desde cualquier pc, desde el sitio en producción,en el error muestra siempre el directorio: C:\Users\Usuario PC\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\Ejemplo\Ejemplo\Clases\PrintReport.cs. Y eso es lo extraño, ya que quedo con la ruta del archivo donde desarrolle el proyecto.

Comment: Danilo así como lo tienes en tu código, el código que muestras va a correr en el servidor, y el reporte será impreso desde el servidor, si deseas imprimir en el lado del navegador, deberás implementar una combinación de código, del lado del servidor generas el reporte (C#) y lo envías al cliente, del lado del cliente recibes lo que te envió el servidor y lo envías a la impresora, esta parte generalmente la desarrollas en JavaScript.

Comment: @MauricioAtanache , buena observación, como enviaría el reporte al cliente?pero de casualidad tienes algún ejemplo por ahí? o algún link donde puede revisar, ya que los que he visto, solo generan vista previa antes de imprimir, y lo que deseo, es imprimir directo a la impresora predeterminada.

Comment: En esta página de MSDN dan un breve ejemplo de cómo podría ser : https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms252091.aspx

Comment: gracias @MauricioAtanache, pero el ejemplo es para aplicación escritorio, el ejemplo que puse es para web, basado en la misma pagina que expone el siguiente ejemplo:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms251837.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396